# Series Editor for InCollection

Tags: bibtex

I need a "series editor" field to finish my record. I am using a `@InCollection` in my BibTeX file.

Using the "note" field the name of the editor is put at the end of the record and I prefer the conventional presentation (editor before title).

I use the `plain` bibliography style.

---

I chose an option. I will use the note field. The reason for this is presented in the code as follows.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}       

\bibliographystyle{plain}

\section{Simple Text}

This is a MWE (Minimal Working Example) to show my problem. I want to cite a chapter from a book. Booktitle and chapters title are diferent, but have the same authors. So, I thought that this was the case for a `@InCollection` record in my BibTeXs file. Here is my problematic reference presented in two forms. In `\cite{NedjahAndMourelle2014c}`, I have included the series editor inside the series field. His name is presented in italic. And the other form, `\cite{NedjahAndMourelle2014d}`, where I've opted to use the note field. I am using the plain bibliographystile. I've decided to use the note field based on `\cite[p.765]{MittelbachEtAl2004}: \textit{note: any additional information that can help the reader}`.

\bibliography{myehw}

\end{document}
```

This is the BibTeX file:

```
@book{MittelbachEtAl2004,
  author = {Mittelbach, F and Goosens, M. and Braams, J. and Carlisle, D. and Rowley, C.},
  title = {The \LaTeX Companion},
  edition = {2\textsuperscript{nd}},
  publisher = {Addison-Wesley},
  year = {2004}
}

@INCOLLECTION{NedjahAndMourelle2014c,
  author = {Nedjah, N. and Mourelle, L.M},
  title = {A Reconfigurable Hardware for Particle Swarm Optimization},
  booktitle = {Hardware for soft computing and soft computing for hardware},
  publisher = {Springer},
  year = {2014},
  volume = {529},
  series = {J. Kacprzyk, series editor, Studies in Computacional Intelligence},
  chapter = {3},
  pages = {28-42},
  address = {Cham}
}

@INCOLLECTION{NedjahAndMourelle2014d,
  author = {Nedjah, N. and Mourelle, L.M},
  title = {A Reconfigurable Hardware for Artificial Neural Neworks},
  booktitle = {Hardware for soft computing and soft computing for hardware},
  publisher = {Springer},
  year = {2014},
  volume = {529},
  series = {Studies in Computacional Intelligence},
  chapter = {5},
  pages = {28-42},
  address = {Cham},
  doi = {10.1007/978-3-319-03110-1},
  note = {J. Kacprzyk, series editor}
}
```

If anyone of you folks can give some other ideas/decisions they are welcome.

Comment: Could you provide the community with a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://goo.gl/dtPzv)? See specifically the section on how to create a minimal BibTeX example in the above link.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436/5001) Which bibliography style do you employ? And how should the names in the `serieseditor` field be formatted -- like those in the `editor` field, or differently?

Comment: Please, see the field "series". I was forced to preceed the title with the name of the editor. I was thinking about some other entry, diferent of incollection, capable of receive such information (the name of the series editor)

Answer (score 4):

I wouldn't bother trying to hack the file `plain.bst` to (a) define a new field called (say) `serieseditor`, (b) define a function called (say) `format.serieseditor`, and (c) edit the functions `incollection`, `inbook` and `book` (and probably a few more) to insert the instruction `format.serieseditor`. (You didn't even indicate how, precisely, the name(s) of the series editor(s) should be formattted.) Instead, I'd append that information to the `series` field as follows:

```
series={Studies in Computational Intelligence \emph{(Janusz Kacprzyk, Series Editor)}},
```

The LaTeX instruction `\emph` is nested: since the contents of `series` are typeset using `\emph`, the `\emph` around `(Janusz Kacprzyk, Series Editor)` serves to typeset the argument in an upright font shape. (The contents of the bib entry below are as given at Springer's website.)

A final remark: I think you didn't get the surname of the entry's second author quite right -- it should be `de Macedo Mourelle`, *not* just "Mourelle". When in doubt, spend more time and effort on getting the names of all authors absolutely right rather than on providing information about series editors.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{zzz.bib}
@incollection{nedjah-demacedomourelle:2014,
  year={2014},
  author={Nedjah, Nadia and de Macedo Mourelle, Luiza},
  title={A Reconfigurable Hardware for Artificial Neural Networks},
  booktitle={Hardware for Soft Computing and Soft Computing  for Hardware},
  series={Studies in Computational Intelligence \emph{(Janusz Kacprzyk, Series Editor)}},
  volume={529},
  doi={10.1007/978-3-319-03110-1_5},
  url={http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/978-3-319-03110-1_5},
  isbn={978-3-319-03109-5},
  publisher={Springer International Publishing},
  chapter = 5,
  pages={59-69},
}
\end{filecontents}
\bibliographystyle{plain}
\begin{document}       
\nocite{*}
\bibliography{zzz}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Very cool, Mico! Thank you! I will apply this corrections. I used the Mourelle, L.M. because Professor Mourelle also uses this entry (http://buscatextual.cnpq.br/buscatextual/visualizacv.do?metodo=apresentar&id=K4780762Y2 at the final she presents her works).

Comment: @jara - well, I went with the way the author's name is given on Springer's own webste, under "how to cite the publication".  If that's *not* how the author herself prefers to write her last name, she might to contact Springer and provide the preferred spelling.